# Visual Studio Code Live Server looks great, but CSS doesn't load in browser

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

When I select "Open with Live Server" for my website, it looks great. The CSS is working correctly and it is doing what I want. But when I try to open the file for one of the pages directly from my computer (no VS Code), the CSS won't load. A page on my website with the exact same code that connects to the exact same CSS code (it is identical except is written in another language) looks perfect, but this one is crap. Any ideas on how to trouble shoot?

---

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  
  /* Extra-Small devices (small phones and whatnot, 600px and under) */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .logo{
      width:50%;
    }
    .tablelinks {
      display: none;
    }
    .tdlinks {
      display: none;
    }
    a,a:visited {
      color:white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .menuimg{
      width:10%;
      height: auto;
      float: right;
      position: absolute;
      top: 30px;
      right: 15px;
      display: none;
    }
    h3{
      color: rgb(144,38,143);
    }
    .button{
        top: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .dropdowncell{
      font-family: Arial;
      color:white;
      font-size:2.7vw;
      background-color: rgb(144,38,143);
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      border-color: rgb(144,38,143);
      margin:0px!important;
    }
    .dropdowntb{
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
  
  
    /*CONTENT*/
    .boxmainmed{
      display: none;
    }
    .boxmainsmall{
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .kidsimage{
      display: initial;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    h2 {
      font-family:Arial;
      color:rgb(0,121,194);
      font-size: 2.2vw;
      padding-top:20px;
      line-height: 1.6;
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
      
    }
    p {  /*line spacing*/
      font-family:Arial;
      color:black;
      font-size:14px;
      padding:10px 1vw;
      line-height: 1.6;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .whatwedo{
      display: initial;
    }
    .txtbox{
      border-top:3px solid rgb(0,121,194);
      border-bottom:3px solid rgb(0,121,194);
      margin: 40px;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
  
    /*SPONSORS*/
    .sponsors {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: rgb(144,38,143);
      width: 100%;
    }
    h1 {
      font-family:Arial;
      color:white;
      font-size:100%!important;
    }
    .chinesethankyou{
      padding-top: 10px;
      font-size: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .plklogo{
      width: 25vw;
      height: auto;
    }
    .ubslogo{
      width: 19.308vw;
      height: auto;
    }
    .cell{
      display: table-cell;
      width: 33%;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
  
  /* Small devices (tablets and whatnots, 600px and up)*/ 
  @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .logo{
      width:30%;
    }
    .tablelinks {
      display: none;
    }
    .tdlinks {
      display: none;
    }
    a,a:visited {
      color:white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .menuimg{
      width:10%;
      height: auto;
      float: right;
      position: absolute;
      top: 30px;
      right: 15px;
      display: none;
    }
    h3{
      color: rgb(144,38,143);
    }
    .button{
        top: 20px;
        right: 20px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .dropdowncell{
      font-family: Arial;
      color:white;
      font-size:2.3vw;
      background-color: rgb(144,38,143);
      padding: 10px 15px;
      text-align: center;
      border-color: rgb(144,38,143);
      margin:0px!important;
    }
    .dropdowntb{
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
  
  
    /*CONTENT*/
    .boxmainsmall{
      display:none;
    }
    .kidsimage{
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      position: static;
      top: 0px;
    }
    h2 {
      font-family:Arial;
      color:rgb(0,121,194);
      font-size: 2.2vw;
      padding:20px 1vw;
      line-height: 1.6;
      display: inline;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    p {  /*line spacing*/
      font-family:Arial;
      color:black;
      font-size:14px;
      line-height: 1.6;
      padding:0px 10px;
      display: inline-block;
      border:1px solid white;
      
    }
    .txtbox{
      width: 100%;
      display: initial;
      position: relative;
    }
    .whatwedo{
      padding:30px 5vw;
      width:  100vw;
      display: table;
      z-index: inherit;
      column-width: 50%;
      margin: 40px 0px;
    }
    
  
    /*SPONSORS*/
    .sponsors {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: rgb(144,38,143);
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
    h1 {
      font-family:Arial;
      color:white;
      font-size:100%!important;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .chinesethankyou{
      padding-top: 10px;
      font-size: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .plklogo{
      width: 25vw;
      height: auto;
    }
    .ubslogo{
      width: 19.308vw;
      height: auto;
    }
    .cell{
      display: table-cell;
      width: 33%;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
  
  /* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up)*/
  @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    /*HEADER*/
    .logo{
      height: auto;
      width: 21%;
      display: initial;
    }
    .tablelinks {
      margin:1.8vw 1.8vw 0px 0px;
      width: 77%;
      float: right;
      position: absolute;
      top:0px;
      right:0px;
      display: table;
    }
    .tdlinks {
      font-family:Arial;
      color:rgb(144,38,143);
      font-size: 1.75vw;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      width: auto;
      padding: .7vmin 1vmin;
      display: table-cell;
    }
    a,a:visited {
      color: rgb(144,38,143);
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline;
      min-inline-size: 50px;
        }
    .dropdownmenu{
      display: none;
    }
  
  
  /*CONTENT*/
    .boxmainmed{
      display: none;
    }
    .boxmainsmall{
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      height: 600px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .kidsimage{
      overflow: hidden;
      width: auto;
      height: inherit;
      display: inline-block;
      z-index:-2;
      position: relative;
    }
    h2 {
      font-family:Arial;
      color:rgb(0,121,194);
      font-size: 2.2vw;
      padding:15px 0px;
      line-height: 1.6;
      display: inline;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    p {  /*line spacing*/
      font-family:Arial;
      color:black;
      font-size:14px;
      line-height: 1.6;
      padding:10px 1vw;
      display: inline; 
      border: none;   
    }
    .txtbox{
      width: 48%;
      height: inherit;
      float: right;
      display: initial;
      position: absolute;
      left:65vw;
      margin-right: 30px;
      min-width: 410px;
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    }
    .whatwedo{
      padding-left:30px;
      margin:auto;
      width:75%;
      min-width: 375px;
      height: inherit;
      display: table;
      z-index: inherit;
      float: left;
      top: 0px;
    }
    /*SPONSORS*/
    .sponsors {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: rgb(144,38,143);
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
      position: relative;
    }
    h1 {
      font-family:Arial;
      color:white;
      font-size:30px!important;
    }
    .plklogo{
      width: 250px;
      height: auto;
      margin: auto;
    }
    .cell{
      display: table-cell;
      text-align: center;
      margin: auto;
    }
  }
```

```html
<html>


<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=big5">
    <title>LTP | Aims & Objectives</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="ltpicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Welcome to Language Training Programme">
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 6.0">
    <meta name="ProgId" content="FrontPage.Editor.Document">
    <meta name="Microsoft Theme" content="none, default">
    <meta name="Microsoft Border" content="none, default">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="stylingaims.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <!--WHY SPACING SOMETIMES WRONG??-->
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <a href="indexwip.html"><img class="logo" src="ltplogo.PNG"></a>
        <nav>
          <table class="tablelinks">
            <tr>
                <td class="tdlinks"><a href="aimsobjecwip.html">Aims & Objectives</a></td>
                <td class="tdlinks"><a href="newswip.html">News</a></td>
                <td class="tdlinks"><a href="careerswip.html">Careers</a></td>
                <td class="tdlinks"><a href=photogalwip.html>Photo Gallery</a></td>
                <td class="tdlinks"><a href="contactwip.html">Contact Us</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdlinks"><a href="aimsobjecschinesewip.html">宗旨</a></td>
                <td class="tdlinks"><a href="newschinesewip.html">最新消息</a></td>
                <td class="tdlinks"><a href="careerschinesewip.html">職位空缺</a></td>
                <td class="tdlinks"><a href="photogalchinesewip.html">圖片集</a></td>
                <td class="tdlinks"><a href="contactchinesewip.html">聯絡我們</a></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
            <div class="w3-container dropdownmenu">
              <button onclick="myFunction('Demo1')" class="w3-btn button"><h3>Menu</h3><img class="menuimg" src="Hamburger_icon.png"></button>
                <div id="Demo1" class="w3-hide  w3-jumbotron">
                  <table class="dropdowntb">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="dropdowncell"><a href="aimsobjecwip.html">Aims & Objectives</a></html></td>
                      <td class="dropdowncell"><a href="newswip.html">News</a></html></td>
                      <td class="dropdowncell"><a href="careerswip.html">Careers</a></html></td>
                      <td class="dropdowncell"><a href=photogalwip.html>Photo Gallery</a></html></td>
                      <td class="dropdowncell"><a href="contactwip.html">Contact Us</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="dropdowncell"><a href="aimsobjecschinesewip.html">宗旨</a></html></td>
                      <td class="dropdowncell"><a href="newschinesewip.html">最新消息</a></html></td>
                      <td class="dropdowncell"><a href="careerschinesewip.html">職位空缺</a></html></td>
                      <td class="dropdowncell"><a href="photogalchinesewip.html">圖片集</a></html></td>
                      <td class="dropdowncell"><a href="contactchinesewip.html">聯絡我們</a></html></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
              <script>
                function myFunction(id) {
                  var x = document.getElementById(id);
                  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
                    x.className += " w3-show";
                  }
                  else { 
                  x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
                  }
                }
              </script>
        </nav>
      </header>
    
    <div class="boxmainsmall">
        <img class="kidsimage" src="ltpstcokphoto_nofade.jpeg"> <!--GET LTP PICTURE-->
        <div class="txtbox">
            <table class="whatwedo">
                <tr><td><h2>Aims and Objectives</h2></td></tr>
                <tr><td>
                  <p>The LTP aims to help every child aged 3 to 18 years in residential care at Po Leung Kuk to become biliterate (able to read and write Chinese and English) and trilingual (able to speak and understand Cantonese, Putonghua, and English). We strive to achieve this through</p>
                  <ul>
                      <li><p>Formal English classes for children and young people from K 1 through Secondary levels,</p></li>
                      <li><p>Elective sessions for Secondary students to develop business and study skills and hobbies through English,</p></li>
                      <li><p>Formal Putonghua classes for children from K 1 to P 6 levels,</p></li>
                      <li><p>Storyteller sessions for all children and young people aged 2 – 18 years,</p></li>
                      <li><p>Informal activities to allow the children and young people to practice their language, and</p></li>
                      <li><p>Celebrations of social and cultural festivals</p></li>
                    </ul>
                </td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxmainmed">
        <img class="kidsimage" src="ltpstcokphoto_nofade.jpeg"> <!--GET LTP PICTURE-->
            <div class="txtbox">
                <table class="whatwedo">
                    <tr><td><h2>Aims and Objectives</h2></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>
                        <p>The LTP aims to help every child aged 3 to 18 years in residential care at Po Leung Kuk to become biliterate (able to read and write Chinese and English) and trilingual (able to speak and understand Cantonese, Putonghua, and English). We strive to achieve this through</p>
                        <ul> 
                            <li><p>Formal English classes for children and young people from K 1 through Secondary levels,</p></li>
                            <li><p>Elective sessions for Secondary students to develop business and study skills and hobbies through English,</p></li>
                            <li><p>Formal Putonghua classes for children from K 1 to P 6 levels,</p></li>
                            <li><p>Storyteller sessions for all children and young people aged 2 – 18 years,</p></li>
                            <li><p>Informal activities to allow the children and young people to practice their language, and</p></li>
                            <li><p>Celebrations of social and cultural festivals</p></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="sponsors" width="100%" id="plswork">
        <tr>
            <td class="cell" style="width:33%;"><h1>Thank You Sponsors</h1></td>
            <td class="cell" style="width:33%;"><h1>谢谢赞助商</h1></td>
            <td class="cell" style="width:33%;"><a href="https://www.poleungkuk.org.hk/"><img src="Po-Leung-Kuk-logo.png" class="plklogo"></a></td>
        <!--LOOKS BAD IN EXPLORER??-->
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In my case, it was caused by a typo in the file path of my css. I have no idea why liver server ignored it and put the file correctly anyways.

The problem was that I had:

```
<link href="/style.css">
```

Instead of:

```
<link href="style.css">
```

So check your files paths. Maybe the problem is there.

Answer (score 2):

Basic live server is configured to launch in the Root folder of the server.
So the relative path for the CSS file will change depending on the launch via live server or directly from the browser.
If I understood correctly.
I encountered this error.

Comment: Good point! Happens if you launch the VSCode server from the wrong root folder. Expanded answer below, thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

### Launch the VSCode "Go Live" server from the website root folder

I had this issue because I launched the live server while working in a VSCode in a folder *above* the html folder where my .html files—my project (and GIT repo) are a level higher. I thought it was a browser issue, searched and found many misleading "solutions".

However, after reading Yannh's answer it occurred to me to **open a new VSCode window of just my website root "html" folder**; hitting "Go Live" from there launched the site complete with CSS.

I kept my original working window (with the full GIT repo) open, making changes there which were **reflected on save** in the **live local browser preview**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use SCSS file and it's not compiled?

Comment: To my knowledge, I used regular CSS. I have posted my code, though, so you can check

Answer (score 0):

Have you used SCSS for styling?

Assuming that you have used SCSS,
Browsers can't interpret SCSS files, so VS Code has an extension for converting SCSS to CSS and linking it to your html file, maybe that's why your file loads while using live server.

Try using https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css to convert your SCSS into CSS and then link it to HTML.

Comment: To my knowledge, I used regular CSS. I have posted my code, though, so you can check

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The reason was that live-server shows mit the page with 25% scaling. Don't know why.
So everything which I have coded was 75% too large.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30845747)